# ¿Como ordenar el código en visual studio code?

Tags: vscode

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio Code. ¿Hay alguna forma de configurar o alguna extension que permita configurar el orden del código de la siguiente manera al guardar?

1-cosntructor

2-Propiedades privadas

3-Propiedades publicas

4-Métodos privados

5-Métodos públicos

Algo así como TypeScript Import Sorter que permite configurar el orden de los imports al guardar.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría leer la documentación de la extensión que quieras modificar, por lo regular se puede hacer con un archivo en formato JSON en la sección de administrador de extensiones vs code, o al menos eso lo he hecho con dos extensiones (en vue y blade en laravel) ya que tengo la mala practica de meter primero el script antes de los templates.